# Valdition Column Formula for Choices (Compelted, Not started, Inprogress)

Tags: validation

In my Task list I got a column named "Status" with 5 different choices,

1. Not Started
2. In Progress
3. Deferred
4. Waiting on someone else
5. Completed

In my task, when it is set to Completed I want the Column status to show a picture. I've uploaded the picture to my site.

Using this formula I can set the choice to Completed and its fine, if I choose Not started I cant continue.

```
=IF(Status="Completed",TRUE,FALSE)
```

But, what I want to do is

```
="<DIV><imgsrc='"
 &IF(Status="Completed"
     ,"http://MY_SITE/SiteAssets/Status%20Images/statuscompleted.png"
    )
 &"'></DIV>"
```

If the status is Completed, it gets the picture and adds it to the status column.

My question is, I've been trying this for hours now and I cant seem to get it to work.

Comment: So what does not work? You don't specify what result you expect and what error you get. Have you set the datatype to Number? This trick for putting HTML in Formulas only works in Views, not in Forms or the Validation Formulas on Forms

Comment: When choosing completed on a task, I want it to show a picture instead of the text "Completed" in the column :)

Comment: In a VIEW? or Form?

Comment: Oh sorry, In a View.

Comment: I editted your formula with linebreaks (SharePoint will ignore those) but you typed ``imgsrc`` So there is a space missing there. And you can exclude the DIVs, they have no purpose. also note the missing FALSE clause will create HTML: ``src='FALSE'`` resulting in a broken image on screen (for the other Status values)

Answer (score 3):

**Note:**

in June 2017, Microsoft disabled the use of JavaScript in a Calculated Column

That means given answers may not apply  for newer SharePoint versions

For long explanation and work arounds see:
[June 13th 2017 Microsoft blocked handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields - how to get the same functionality back](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f/218110#218110)

---

**Original answer:**

You do not need the DIVs

And you may want to rewrite you code to produce a (Status) image for all Status values:

```
="<img src='http://MY_SITE/SiteAssets/Status%20Images/status"
&[Status]
&".png'>"
```

*Do not forget to set the datatype to Number!* This only works in Views not on Forms!

So you need images:

```
statusCompleted.png
statusIn Progress.png
etc...
```

When building Formulas it is good practice to work from within Notepad (or any decent text-editor) and format you code with Linebreaks and indentations.

Then copy/paste to SharePoint which will ignore all that formatting.

#### SP2013/Online : CSR

You can use JavaScript to render Views and Forms using SharePoints (new) **Client Side Rendering** techniques

The [iCSR.js](http://iCSR.github.io) support library gets you started with CSR (JavaScript) development

#### CalcMaster Bookmarklet

I have answered a lot of Formula questions, they are all tagged with ICC (Inline Calculated Columns), easy to find with:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=ICC

If you know (or want to learn) what a Browser Bookmarklet is; I have Open-Sourced code that makes Formula editting a bit easier; Main feature: it does a syntax check on every keystroke.

https://github.com/Danny-Engelman/CalcMaster

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This Link would solve your issue

http://blogs.technet.com/b/jay/archive/2013/06/17/how-to-display-images-in-a-calculated-column-of-a-sharepoint-list.aspx

Comment: Doesnt work, when I put status Completed i got a error, "Coloumn Validationo Failed"

Comment: Kindly try below formulas..

="<DIV><imgsrc='"&IF([Status]="Completed","http://MY_SITE/SiteAssets/Status%20Images/statuscompleted.png")&"'></DIV>"

Comment: ="<DIV><imgsrc='"&IF([Status]="Completed","http://MY_SITE/SiteAssets/Status%20Images/statuscompleted.png","null")&"'></DIV>"

Comment: Didnt work, choosing "Completed" on the task give me Column Validation Failed

Comment: @Ankitkumar, it is good practice here to not only paste links but also post (part of) the blog with the relevant code. That way the answers can be indexed by StackOverflow as well.

Comment: @DannyEngelman  will make sure that from next time part of blogs will be added with useful links....